# Java how to increment a string of an integer with leading zeros?

Tags: java

Is there a shortcut or way to increment a string that is a number with leading zeros?

For example:

```
000
001
002
003
...
etc
```

Comment: If there's leading zeros, it's a String, not a number. Please explain more about your situation and what you've tried). Is your question "How do it convert a numeric String to an integer, increment it, then render it back to a String with the same length as the input, factoring in that there may be leading zeroes in the input"?

Comment: The problem is not clear. Do you mean how to create a sequence of such strings, where a following string is incremented by 1? Or do you expect to have a method that receives such string as an input and increments it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
static final Pattern NUMBER = Pattern.compile("\\d+");

static String increment(String input) {
    return NUMBER.matcher(input)
        .replaceFirst(s -> String.format(
            "%0" + s.group().length() + "d",
            Integer.parseInt(s.group()) + 1));
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(increment("001"));
    System.out.println(increment("012345"));
    System.out.println(increment("ABC0123"));
}
```

output:

```
002
012346
ABC0124
```

Answer (score 3):

Parse the string as an long, increment it, then format it using the length of the input as the width of the output:

```
str = String.format("%0" + str.length() + "d", Long.parseLong(str) + 1);
```

This works for any width of input (up to 19 digits anyway).

Note: Overflowing the width of the input string will not stay within the width. eg `"999"` will produce `"1000"`

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following,

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "001";
        Integer i = Integer.parseInt(s);
        i++;
        s = String.format("%0" + s.length() + "d", i);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvoting because this only works for OP's "For example" where the number is 3 characters in length. `String s = "0001"`will give `002`.